# How can I pull elements from a file when needed?

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to write a program to create player objects and save them to a file(Which I have done).
The problem I am trying to resolve is, I want to be able to pull the players out of the file when needed. So if I want to get the information for just player 1 or player n, with just their details is there a way I can pull it from the file if needed?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much for your help in advance.

```
package p;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Runner {

    public static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt", true);
        PlayerData player = null;
        List<PlayerData> players = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("How many players do you want to register? : ");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Plz enter Name : ");
            String name = input.next();
            writer.write("Name: " + name + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.println("Plz enter age : ");
            String age = input.next();
            writer.write("Age: " + age + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.println("Plz enter Player_id : ");
            String player_id = input.next();
            writer.write("Player_id: " + player_id + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.println("Plz enter agent_id : ");
            String agent_id = input.next();
            writer.write("Agent_id:" + agent_id + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.println("Plz enter status : ");
            String status = input.next();
            writer.write("Status: " + status + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.println("Plz enter position : ");
            String position = input.next();
            writer.write("Position: " + position + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.println("Plz enter valuation : ");
            Double valuation = input.nextDouble();
            writer.write("Value: " + valuation + System.lineSeparator());
            writer.write("\n " + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.println("\n");
            player = new PlayerData(name, age, player_id, agent_id, valuation, status, position);
            players.add(player);

            System.out.println("Information Entered: \n" + player + "\n" + "Name : " + name + "\n" + "Age: " + age
                    + "Player id: " + player_id + "\n" + "Agent id: " + agent_id + "\n" + "Player Value: " + valuation
                    + "\n" + "Player Status:" + status + "\n" + "Player position:" + position + "\n");

            writer.close();
            if (players.size() == num)

                break;
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("output.txt")));
        String line = " ";
        System.out.println("Current Players on the transfer List \n");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line);

        } // while

        reader.close();// close reader

    }

}
```

Comment: Not really, given that player names can be different lengths, hence the records in your file are of different lengths. This is the time to switch to using a database - even a simple one, like SQLite, Derby or H2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of this, first while loop should get you to a place where the player name matches your input name , next while will get the next 7 lines into the playerinfo list.

```
public FileReader fr = new FileReader("path/to/your/file");
public BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String playerName = "John";
String line;
List<String> playerInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
while((line =  br.readLine()) != null){
 if (line.contains(playerName))
 {
    int numLines = 7;
    playerInfo.add(line);
    while((line =  br.readLine()) != null && numLines >= 1){
        playerInfo.add(line);
        numLines --;
        break;
    }
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: After a few changes (with the breaks) that works great man, thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might try using Java Object Serialization:

[Java Object Serialization (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html)

I guess regardless of whether you use your current method or Object Serialization, you could save each player to a different file.

Comment: That would still require accessing the file serially, not going directly to player 1 or player N.